# Position between two points?

Tags: geometry

I have a python app where I need to find a position that is exactly in the middle between two screen coordinates, but I can't seem to find an algorithm to do this. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 22):

X coordinate is (x1 + x2) / 2

y coordinate is (y1 + y2) / 2

Answer (score 9):

You want to find the midpoint of a line. 
Here is a little article to explain the math behind it. 
<sub><del>http://regentsprep.org/regents/math/midpoint/Lmidpoint.htm</del> (Dead Link)</sub>

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint

[image: Midpoint formula image]

Basically your algorithm will look like this:

```
midX = (x1 + x2) / 2

midY = (y1 + y2) / 2
```

Answer (score 5):

This is elementary geometry:

- point1(x1,y1)
- point2(x2,y2)
- point_in_the_middle(x=(x1+x2)/2,y=(y1+y2)/2)

Or did you mean something else ?

dmckee: Yes dear! :)

Comment: +1 for codeishness, even if tehvan beat you to the punch, but please format it!

Answer (score 1):

The middle point (C) should be the average of the two points (A, B):

```
Cx = (Ax + Bx) / 2
Cy = (Ay + By) / 2
```